# CSS set the appropriate dasharray value on this animation

Tags: css, animation, signature

How can I set the appropriate value on dasharray to have the signature wrote from left to right and without overrun the SVG length? Is there an easy part to check out different values?

```css
/* Take a bunch of the SVG attributes and place them here for the sake of dryness */

path,
line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #2a3745;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.stroke-ec {
  stroke-dasharray: 330;
  animation: write2 5s infinite linear;
}


/*  keyframes */

@keyframes write2 {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 340;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="signature" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 280 100" xml:space="preserve">

    <path class="stroke-ec" d="M112.1,46.8c-10.1,3.1-20.7,4.4-31.3,4c-5.3-0.2-10.6-0.9-15.9-2c-1.2-0.3-2.4-0.5-3.6-0.8 c-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.3-1.8-0.5c-0.1,0-0.7-0.1-0.9-0.2c-0.3,0-0.4-0.2-0.3-0.5c-0.1-0.4,0-0.7,0.4-0.8c2.1-1.4,4.6-2.3,6.9-3.3 c9.6-4.2,19.9-7.2,30.4-7.4c8.3-0.2,18.3,1.2,23.8,8.2c3.4,4.2,4.1,10.3,1.7,15.2c-2.2,4.7-7.1,7.8-12.2,8.1 c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8c3.3-8.4,8-16.1,13.8-23.1c2.8-3.4,5.9-6.7,8.9-10c3.1-3.2,6.1-6.5,9.5-9.4c4-3.4,8.4-6.2,12.9-9 c-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.7-0.8-1c-8.6,9-17.2,18-25.9,27.1c-0.3,0.3-0.3,0.8,0.1,1c1.6,0.7,3,0.1,4.4-0.5c2.2-0.9,4.3-1.9,6.5-2.9 c4.3-1.9,8.5-3.7,12.8-5.6c0.7-0.3,0.2-1.3-0.5-1.1c-6.1,1.5-11.5,5.1-15.3,10.2c-0.3,0.4,0.1,0.9,0.5,0.9 c18.2,1.3,36.4,1.9,54.7,1.8c5.2,0,10.4-0.1,15.6-0.2c0.8,0,0.8-1.3,0-1.2c-18.2,0.5-36.5,0.3-54.7-0.6 c-5.2-0.3-10.4-0.6-15.6-0.9c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.5,0.9c3.5-4.8,8.7-8.2,14.5-9.6c-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.5-1.1c-3.7,1.6-7.3,3.2-11,4.8 c-1.8,0.8-3.6,1.6-5.4,2.4c-0.9,0.4-1.8,0.8-2.7,1.2c-1,0.4-2.3,1.2-3.4,0.6c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.1,1c8.6-9,17.2-18,25.9-27.1 c0.5-0.5-0.1-1.4-0.8-1c-3.9,2.4-7.7,4.9-11.3,7.7c-3.7,2.9-7,6.3-10.2,9.7c-6.3,6.7-12.5,13.5-17.4,21.3 c-2.7,4.3-4.9,8.8-6.7,13.5c-0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.6,0.8c4.6-0.3,9-2.5,11.8-6.2c3-4,3.9-9.5,2.3-14.2c-2.9-9-12.9-12.5-21.5-13.3 c-11.6-1-23.3,1.8-34,6.2c-2.7,1.1-5.3,2.3-7.9,3.5c-1.2,0.6-4.5,2-3,3.9c0.6,0.8,1.9,0.9,2.8,1.1c1.5,0.4,3,0.8,4.5,1.1 c2.8,0.6,5.7,1.1,8.6,1.4c13.2,1.6,26.7,0.4,39.5-3.4C113.2,47.8,112.9,46.6,112.1,46.8L112.1,46.8z"/>
</svg>
```

The stroke must be filled once and then the animation restarts from the left.

Comment: (The syntax highlighting for the CSS part is out of whack. But the hint is required for the snippet to run.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `<path>` is an outline: so it contains inner and outer contours

[image: signature]

So your animation will appear to run twice.
You'll need to draw a "inner/center" path for the stroke animation.

### [`<pathLength>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength): set relative/computed length

From mdn docs

> The pathLength attribute lets authors specify a total length for the
> path, in user units. This value is then used to calibrate the
> browser's distance calculations with those of the author, by scaling
> all distance computations using the ratio pathLength / (computed value
> of path length).

This way we can use relative `dash-array` values like so

```
<path pathLength="100" d="" />  

stroke-dashoffset:100
```

```css
path,
line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #2a3745;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.stroke-ec {
  stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
  animation: write2 5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes write2 {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="signature" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 280 100" xml:space="preserve">

  <clipPath id="clip">
      <path  d="M207.1 44.6c-18.2 0.5-36.5 0.3-54.7-0.6c-4.8-0.3-9.6-0.6-14.4-0.8c1.7-2.2 3.7-4 6-5.4c2.4-1.1 4.9-2.2 7.3-3.3c0.2 0 0.3-0.1 0.5-0.1c0 0 0 0 0-0.1c0.1 0 0.2-0.1 0.3-0.1c0.7-0.3 0.2-1.3-0.5-1.1c-3.1 0.8-6 2.1-8.6 3.8c-0.9 0.4-1.8 0.8-2.7 1.2c-1.8 0.8-3.6 1.6-5.4 2.4c-0.9 0.4-1.8 0.8-2.7 1.2s-1.7 0.8-2.6 0.8c8.4-8.7 16.7-17.4 25.1-26.2c0.1-0.1 0.2-0.1 0.3-0.2s0-0.1-0.1-0.1c0.2-0.4-0.2-1-0.7-0.9c0 0 0 0 0 0s0 0 0 0s-0.1 0.1-0.2 0.1c-3.9 2.4-7.7 4.9-11.3 7.7s-7 6.3-10.2 9.7c-3.7 3.9-7.4 7.9-10.8 12.1c-3.9-6.7-12.6-9.5-20.1-10.2c-11.6-1-23.3 1.8-34 6.2c-2.7 1.1-5.3 2.3-7.9 3.5c-1.2 0.6-4.5 2-3 3.9c0.6 0.8 1.9 0.9 2.8 1.1c1.5 0.4 3 0.8 4.5 1.1c2.8 0.6 5.7 1.1 8.6 1.4c13.2 1.6 26.7 0.4 39.5-3.4c1.1-0.5 0.8-1.7 0-1.5c-10.1 3.1-20.7 4.4-31.3 4c-5.3-0.2-10.6-0.9-15.9-2c-1.2-0.3-2.4-0.5-3.6-0.8c-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.3-1.8-0.5c-0.1 0-0.7-0.1-0.9-0.2s-0.4-0.2-0.3-0.5c-0.1-0.4 0-0.7 0.4-0.8c2.1-1.4 4.6-2.3 6.9-3.3c9.6-4.2 19.9-7.2 30.4-7.4c8.3-0.2 18.3 1.2 23.8 8.2c0.5 0.6 0.9 1.3 1.3 2c-2.1 2.7-4.2 5.5-6 8.4c-2.7 4.3-4.9 8.8-6.7 13.5c-0.1 0.4 0.2 0.8 0.6 0.8c4.6-0.3 9-2.5 11.8-6.2c3-4 3.9-9.5 2.3-14.2c-0.2-0.6-0.4-1.2-0.7-1.7c0.4-0.5 0.9-1.1 1.3-1.6c2.8-3.4 5.9-6.7 8.9-10s6.1-6.5 9.5-9.4c2.7-2.3 5.5-4.2 8.4-6.1c-7.4 7.7-14.7 15.4-22.2 23.2c-0.3 0.3-0.3 0.8 0.1 1c1.6 0.7 3 0.1 4.4-0.5c2.2-0.9 4.3-1.9 6.5-2.9c0.1 0 0.1-0.1 0.2-0.1c-1.2 1.1-2.2 2.3-3.2 3.6c-0.3 0.4 0.1 0.9 0.5 0.9c18.2 1.3 36.4 1.9 54.7 1.8c5.2 0 10.4-0.1 15.6-0.2c0.8 0 0.8-1.3 0-1.2zm-85.6 14.1c-2.1 4.4-6.5 7.4-11.2 8c2.9-7.1 6.8-13.7 11.5-19.8c1.6 3.7 1.5 8.1-0.3 11.8z" />
  </clipPath>
  
  <path pathLength="100" clip-path="url(#clip)" class="stroke-ec" id="stroke" d="M112.9 47.4c-24.7 8.3 -56.1 1.9 -56.1 -0.3s22.5 -12.2 40.9 -12.2c22.1 0 25.8 11.9 25.8 17.2c0 12.6 -11.5 15 -14 15c0 0 5.1 -15.7 20.4 -31c8.1 -8 23.2 -21.4 24.4 -20.3s-27.2 27.6 -25.4 27.6c1.1 0 21.1 -9.3 22.4 -9.6c1.3 -0.3 -12.6 4.5 -14.4 9.7c0 0 18.4 1.9 34.8 1.9s36.4 -0.3 36.4 -0.3" />
  

</svg>
```

The solid outline path can be used as a clip-path to emulate variable stroke widths.
For a perfect result you'll need to tweak the animated "center" stroke to prevent undesired effects.

### Further reading

See **ccprog's** great tutorial on css-tricks ["Animate Calligraphy with SVG"](https://css-tricks.com/animate-calligraphy-with-svg/)

Answer (score -1):

To set the appropriate value for the `stroke-dasharray` property in order to have the signature wrote from left to right without exceeding the SVG length, you need to consider the length of the path.

In the provided SVG code snippet, the `stroke-dasharray` property is set to `330`, and the animation is defined to write the signature over a duration of `5s`. However, the length of the path is not known from the given code. To determine the exact length of the path, you can use JavaScript or external tools. Here's an example of how you can calculate the length of the path using JavaScript:

```js
// Get the length of the path 
const signaturePath = document.querySelector('#signature path');
const pathLength = signaturePath.getTotalLength();
console.log(pathLength); // Display the path length in the console
```

```html
<svg id="signature" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 280 100" xml:space="preserve"> <!-- Add your SVG path here --> </svg>
```

Once you have the length of the path, you can adjust the `stroke-dasharray` value accordingly to ensure the signature is written without exceeding the length of the path. The `stroke-dasharray` property defines the length of dashes and gaps in the stroke. To achieve the desired effect, you can experiment with different values until you find one that suits your needs.

For example, if the calculated path length is `500`, you could set `stroke-dasharray` to a value like `500` or `500 1000` to control the length of dashes and gaps in the stroke animation. Remember to update the CSS code in the SVG accordingly with the new `stroke-dasharray` value:

By adjusting the `stroke-dasharray` value and experimenting with different lengths, you can achieve the desired effect of writing the signature from left to right without exceeding the length of the SVG.

```js
// Get the length of the path 
const signaturePath = document.querySelector('#signature path');
const pathLength = signaturePath.getTotalLength();
console.log(pathLength);
```

```css
.stroke-ec {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  /* Adjust the value as per your needs */
  animation: write2 5s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<svg id="signature" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 280 100" xml:space="preserve"> <!-- Add your SVG path here --> </svg>
```

Once you have the length of the path, you can adjust the stroke-dasharray value accordingly to ensure the signature is written without exceeding the length of the path. The stroke-dasharray property defines the length of dashes and gaps in the stroke. To achieve the desired effect, you can experiment with different values until you find one that suits your needs. For example, if the calculated path length is 500, you could set stroke-dasharray to a value like 500 or 500 1000 to control the length of dashes and gaps in the stroke animation. Remember to update the CSS code in the SVG accordingly with the new stroke-dasharray value:

```
    .stroke-ec { 
    stroke-dasharray: 500; 
    /* Adjust the value as per your needs */ 
    animation: write2 5s infinite linear; 
    }
```

By adjusting the stroke-dasharray value and experimenting with different lengths, you can achieve the desired effect of writing the signature from left to right without exceeding the length of the SVG.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Muhammad Madni!

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.